# Understanding activity return transitions

Tags: android, android-transitions, activity-transition

I am currently using a custom shared element transition for when I launch Activity B from activity A. Everything works perfectly.

I want to use another custom `Transition` that doesn't involve any shared elements for the return transition from activity B back to activity A. However, I am having trouble with several parts:

1. How do I tell the framework that the return transition doesn't involve any shared elements?
2. What are the start and end values for the transition in a return transition? For the enter transition, I mostly manipulated activity B's views as they are drawn on top of activity A's. What happens in a return transition?

Appreciate any help I can get!

EDIT:

Further investigation revealed that my return transition's `createAnimator` isn't even being called even though I'm calling `setSharedElementReturnTransition`. But I know the set call is doing something because it now doesn't try to reverse the original enter animation (default behavior) and instead of just overlaps the two views.

EDIT #2:

After looking at George Mount's answer, I added

```
@Override
public void captureStartValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    transitionValues.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void captureEndValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    transitionValues.view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

This is now causing my return transition's `createAnimator` to at least run albeit the animation is still weird. Why does the visibility matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the culprit that was causing my return transition's `createAnimator` to not run. Apparently, if the transition framework thinks that the starting and ending states for the transitioning views are the same, it won't create an animator. Therefore, adding some dummy but different values into `captureStartState` and `captureEndState` finally caused my return transition to run properly.

Answer (score 3):

1. You must set the SharedElementCallback and in onMapSharedElements, clear the shared element map. That will eliminate the shared element from your transition.
2. This depends on which transition you're talking about. Specifically the return transition's start end end values are View.VISIBLE and View.INVISIBLE. But there are several transitions happening when returning:

**Return Transition**: non-shared elements are removed from the scene in Activity B by changing their visibility.

**Shared Element Return Transition**: The shared element in Activity B starts where it is when `finishAfterTransition` is called and ends where Activity A says the shared element is. This can be adjusted by `SharedElementCallback`'s `onSharedElementStart` and `onSharedElementEnd`, which are called in reverse during return.

**Reenter Transition**: non-shared element views from Activity A change their visibility.

**Shared Element Reenter Transition**: usually nothing, but the shared element can do something special after it lands in Activity A.

Comment: If I clear the shared elements map, won't that remove shared element transition from my enter transition too? I only want to remove it from the return transition.

Comment: Also can you clarify return/reenter for "changing their visibility"? If I want to do something custom such as sliding the elements out for the return transition, what does the visibility have to do with anything?

Comment: For your first question, yes. However, you can set a different SharedElementCallback when you leave or have different logic. WRT visibility: slide, explode, and fade transitions are all visibility transitions (check the inheritance) and respond to changes in visibility as well as absence. If you want something custom, derive your class from Visibility as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I now understand transitions a little better :) I actually found the culprit that was the cause of my bug which I'll add an answer here. Here's the bounty!